# Is DTLS supported by Schannel on Windows 7?

Tags: dts, schannel

I have seen conflicting answers to this question. How would I activate a `DTLS` session using `InitializeSecurityContext`?

Answer (score 0):

DTLS is present in Windows 8 and later.

When creating your credentials you need to the `SCHANNEL_CRED` `grbitEnabledProtocols` to include `SP_PROT_DTLS1_0_SERVER` or one of the other DTLS values from schannel.h

You then need to select the correct requirements for the "required attributes" when creating your context (things like `ISC_REQ_DATAGRAM` from sspi.h).

See [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh831771.aspx) for some more information.