# DTLS using SChannel: shutdown routine's InitializeSecurityContext returns SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN

Tags: winapi, dtls, schannel

The client is using SChannel to handle the DTLS connection, where the server uses OpenSSL.
Everything works fine until the client tries to close the connection (I used this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/shutting-down-an-schannel-connection)).

Here is the client shutdown routine:

```
         SecBufferDesc BuffDesc;
         SecBuffer Buffer;
         SECURITY_STATUS sspi_ret;
         SecBuffer outbuf;
         SecBufferDesc outbuf_desc;

         DWORD dwshut = SCHANNEL_SHUTDOWN;

         Buffer->BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
         Buffer->pvBuffer = &dwshut;
         Buffer->cbBuffer = sizeof(dwshut);
         init_sec_buffer_desc(&BuffDesc, &Buffer, 1);

         sspi_ret = ApplyControlToken(&c->ctxt_handle, &BuffDesc);
         if (sspi_ret != SEC_E_OK)
             log(h, LOG_ERROR, "ApplyControlToken failed\n");


         outbuf->BufferType = SECBUFFER_EMPTY;
         outbuf->pvBuffer = NULL;
         outbuf->cbBuffer = 0;
         init_sec_buffer_desc(&outbuf_desc, &outbuf, 1);

         sspi_ret = InitializeSecurityContext(&c->cred_handle, &c->ctxt_handle, s->host,
                                              c->request_flags, 0, 0, NULL, 0, &c->ctxt_handle,
                                              &outbuf_desc, &c->context_flags, &c->ctxt_timestamp);
         if (sspi_ret == SEC_E_OK || sspi_ret == SEC_I_CONTEXT_EXPIRED) {
             ret = write(s->tcp, outbuf.pvBuffer, outbuf.cbBuffer);
             FreeContextBuffer(outbuf.pvBuffer);
             if (ret < 0 || ret != outbuf.cbBuffer)
                 log(h, LOG_ERROR, "Failed to send close message\n");
         }
```

The thing is that InitializeSecurityContext returns SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN and doesn't init the output buffer - so I don't have a close_notify msg to send to the server.

At this point i'm  not sure if i'm doing something wrong, or that I cannot expect SChannel to work accordingly to OpenSSL's shutdown routine.
Any help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

As suggested, I tried using a different token type - SECBUFFER_TOKEN. Because I do not use the ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY flag, I allocated a buffer. I got the SEC_I_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT, so I added a loop.

Now it returns SEC_I_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT twice, and on the third call returns SEC_E_INVALID_HANDLE. Any ideas?

```
         SecBufferDesc BuffDesc;
         SecBuffer Buffer;
         SECURITY_STATUS sspi_ret;
         SecBuffer outbuf;
         SecBufferDesc outbuf_desc;

         DWORD dwshut = SCHANNEL_SHUTDOWN;

         Buffer->BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
         Buffer->pvBuffer = &dwshut;
         Buffer->cbBuffer = sizeof(dwshut);
         init_sec_buffer_desc(&BuffDesc, &Buffer, 1);

         sspi_ret = ApplyControlToken(&c->ctxt_handle, &BuffDesc);
         if (sspi_ret != SEC_E_OK)
             log(h, LOG_ERROR, "ApplyControlToken failed\n");

         BYTE output_msg[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
         memset(output_msg, 0, MAX_MSG_SIZE);
         outbuf->BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;
         outbuf->pvBuffer = output_msg;
         outbuf->cbBuffer = MAX_MSG_SIZE;
         init_sec_buffer_desc(&outbuf_desc, &outbuf, 1);
         int size = 0;

         do {
             sspi_ret = InitializeSecurityContext(&c->cred_handle, &c->ctxt_handle, s->host,
                                              c->request_flags, 0, 0, NULL, 0, &c->ctxt_handle,
                                              &outbuf_desc, &c->context_flags, &c->ctxt_timestamp);
             if (sspi_ret == SEC_I_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT) {
                 size += outbuf->cbBuffer;
                 outbuf.pvBuffer = output_msg + size;
                 outbuf.cbBuffer = MAX_MSG_SIZE;
             }
         } while (sspi_ret == SEC_I_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT);

         if (sspi_ret == SEC_E_OK || sspi_ret == SEC_I_CONTEXT_EXPIRED) {
             ret = write(s->tcp, outbuf.pvBuffer, outbuf.cbBuffer);
             FreeContextBuffer(outbuf.pvBuffer);
             if (ret < 0 || ret != outbuf.cbBuffer)
                 log(h, LOG_ERROR, "Failed to send close message\n");
         }
```

Comment: replace `outbuf->BufferType = SECBUFFER_EMPTY;` to `outbuf->BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN;`

Comment: Already tried that, got: SEC_E_INSUFFICIENT_MEMORY - Not enough memory is available to complete this request.
Then I added the allocate memory for me flag, it returned SEC_I_MESSAGE_FRAGMENT. So I looped and called InitializeSecurityContext several times until the same SEC_E_INVALID_TOKEN returned again.

Comment: in this case you have some another errors. for code with outbuf->BufferType = SECBUFFER_TOKEN work ok

Comment: What flags are you using? do you indicate outbuf->pvBuffer = NULL and     outbuf->cbBuffer = 0 ?

Comment: Please review the new edit.

Comment: i use [this](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/blob/master/ASIO/ssl.cpp#L458) code for shutdown and it work ok for me

Comment: Thanks, but is it for DTLS? it seems that the shutdown routine is not relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678618/dtls-using-schannel?rq=1

Comment: this is for general windows schannel. you got exactly error from here. what is transport ( tcp, udp, etc ) - not relevant here

Comment: Why isn't it relevant? it seems in the link I sent that it is and therefore shutting down this way won't work.

Comment: you got error from schannel. schannel work with input and output data. it not care about transport. how you send/receiver data to another side. you not got error from remote side, but from local api call

Comment: Curl uses SECBUFFER_EMPTY https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/21248e052dbd0db33e8999aeeb919fb6f32c9567/lib/vtls/schannel.c#L2193